# Site working with Live Server, does not work when I start it from Files

Tags: html, css, file, bootstrap-5, liveserver

*I've tried few browsers and site works fine with Live Server in every single case. In the other hand when I start it with Firefox/Chrome site won't load my style.css at all, when I use Edge I get a message that file is missing. Here is my html and css code.*

*-----index.html-----*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/bootstrap/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/bootstrap/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>Web Projekat</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbackgroundcolor navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <!-- Container wrapper -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Toggle button -->
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
          data-mdb-target="#navbarCenteredExample"
          aria-controls="navbarCenteredExample"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
        <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center"
          id="navbarCenteredExample"
        >
          <!-- Left links -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item pe-5 fs-4">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/html/gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html"
                ><img
                  class="skate"
                  src="/media/icons8-skateboard-64 white.png"
                  alt="Home"
              /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ps-5 fs-4">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/html/shop.html">Shop</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Left links -->
        </div>
        <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
      </div>
      <!-- Container wrapper -->
    </nav>
    <script src="/bootstrap/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*-----style.css-----*

```
.skate {
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
}
.navbackgroundcolor {
background-color: #464648;
}
.navbar-link {
color: #c7c7c7 !important;
}
body {
background-size: cover;
background-color: #392727 !important;
}
```

*I've tried renaming files, changing position of lines in the code, few browsers, few similar posts about this, making different files and idk what else and nothing worked.*

Comment: What do you mean "start it from files"??

Comment: I mean right click on index.html, open with, Google Chrome (or any other browser).

Comment: Your html loads CSS And JS from relative paths: `<script src="/bootstrap/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`. Live server can handle that, since it can work relative to the root of the server application. That won't work by right-clicking on files to open them.

Comment: How can I fix it? I think I get it and I don't want to sound really stupid but my bootstrap files are in the same folder as my project: 
project folder\bootstrap\bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist\js/bootstrap.js
\project folder\index.html

Comment: You don't fix it - you serve your pages through a web server - with live server. Why is this a problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know for myb further projects

Comment: Web project are meant to be served by web servers. So this is how you do it. That's my advice. If you want to provide an absolute path to a file on your machine you can, or you can put your js and css in the exact same folder as index.html and just use the filenames when you refer to them in your link and script tags. But this is not good for deployment or organizing projects as they grow in size.

Answer (score 1):

try adding it like this ../css/style.css